# Make button usable by pressing Enter only when visible

Tags: jquery, visibility

From what I understand, if I have a button bound to the Enter key, it can still be clicked with Enter even when invisible. I'm trying to make it so that it is only clickable with Enter when it's visible.

```
if($("#answerButton").is(":visible")){
  $(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
      $("#answerButton").click();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check button is visible or not when keypress event is firing, In your case the keypress event will bind if the element is visible initially

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if($("#answerButton").is(":visible")){
        if (e.which == 13){
            $("#answerButton").click();
        }
    }
});
```